# My flair has turned against me

Tags: bug, combined-flair

I usually keep a copy of my "combined flair" in the "About me" part of my profile, and I noticed yesterday that it has turned into something rather different:

[image: evil flair replacement]

Here's my usual flair link, with image:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/d0c456330b54457d8bd65294962afb12.png
```

[image]

(I guess one way to tell whether the problem has been solved is if you see flair instead of the warning image there when you read the question.)

Anyway, seems like a bug or temporary problem.

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer -- that did it.